# Pandas merge rows together to get the same lenght of strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp, numbers

I would like to merge consecutive rows so that the length of the text (measured in words) is similar for every row.

Consider the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['Tyger Tyger burning.', 3],
                    ['bright.', 1],
                   ['In the forests of the night.', 6],
                   ['What immortal.', 2],  
                   ['hand or eye could frame thy fearful symmetry.',  8],
                   ['In what distant deeps or skies.', 6],
                   ['Burnt the fire of thine eyes.', 6]
                    ],columns=['SENTENCE','NO_WORDS'])
```

```
                                        SENTENCE  NO_WORDS
0                           Tyger Tyger burning.         3
1                                        Bright.         1
2                   In the forests of the night.         6
3                                 What immortal.         2
4  Hand or eye could frame thy fearful symmetry.         8
5                In what distant deeps or skies.         6
6                  Burnt the fire of thine eyes.         6
```

The desired output would be to have at least 10 words in each row, but once this condition is met, no more additional rows should be merged. The sentences cannot be split.

```
                                            SENTENCE  NO_WORDS
0  Tyger Tyger burning. Bright. In the forests of...        10
1  What immortal. Hand or eye could frame thy fea...        10
2  In what distant deeps or skies. Burnt the fire...        12
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not going to post an answer as I think my maths is probably a bit off and there's probably a better way, but something like: `df.groupby(df['NO_WORDS'].cumsum() // 11, as_index=False).agg({'SENTENCE': ' '.join, 'NO_WORDS': sum})` is probably the direction you want to be heading in...

Comment: Do you have any ideas as to where to start? Perhaps something like `cumsum`, floor div, groupby, and concat?

Comment: @JonClements you should post as an answer, it is a perfectly valid solution (I had a similar solution)

Comment: Brilliant, that's exactly what I meant @JonClements